# Y movement in Space Invaders (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a Space Invaders clone. The enemies start in the left side of the screen, go to right and then down, but i want to know how to stop and go to left, as the original videogames. Thanks!

```
  #pragma strict

// ESTADOS DEL ESCUADRON

enum TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO{
    ABAJO = 0,
    IZQ = 1,
    DER = 2,
    PARADO = 3
}

var estado : TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO;
private var cacheTransform : Transform;
var limitelateral : int;
var velocidad : float ;
private var vectorMov : Vector3;

function Start () {
    cacheTransform = transform;

}

function Update () {
    ComprobarEstado();
}


function ComprobarEstado(){
    switch(estado){
        case TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.ABAJO:
            // TODO: mueve abajo el escuadron
            if(cacheTransform.position.x <= limitelateral) {
            vectorMov = Vector3.down * velocidad;
            cacheTransform.Translate(vectorMov * Time.deltaTime);
            } else {
                estado = TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.IZQ;

            }
        break;
        case TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.DER:
            // TODO: mueve der el escuadron
            // Si el escuadron esta menor que el limite, mueve derecha
            if(cacheTransform.position.x < limitelateral){
                vectorMov = Vector3.right * velocidad;
                cacheTransform.Translate(vectorMov * Time.deltaTime);
            } else {
                estado = TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.ABAJO;

            }
        break;
        case TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.IZQ:
            // TODO: mueve izq el escuadron
            if(cacheTransform.position.x > limitelateral)
            {
                vectorMov = Vector3.left * velocidad;
                cacheTransform.Translate(vectorMov * Time.deltaTime);
            } else {
                estado = TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.ABAJO;

            }
        break;
        case TIPOS_MOVIMIENTO.PARADO:
            // TODO: detiene el escuadron
            if(cacheTransform.position.y < limitelateral){
                vectorMov = Vector3.down * 0;
                cacheTransform.Translate(vectorMov * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        break;
    }

}
```

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem into two: Create a method that can paint all the (surviving) enemies relative to some offset and create an iterator which gives you all the offsets.

Here is some pseudo code for the iterator:

```
init() {
   x = 0
   y = 0

   width = 5
   maxHeight = 5
}

next() {
    x ++
    if( x >= width ) {
        y ++
        x = 0
    }
    return y < maxHeight
}

getX() {
    return ( y & 1 ) ? width - x : x
}
```

Call `next()` until it returns false and `getX()` to get the correct X position for the current y offset

Comment: I am a very new beginner in JS so i don't understand the most part of the code.

It dosnt matter if is "unperfect", but i want to make the movement as a entire block to learn these script.

Anyway, it's a gret answer, than you very much :)

Comment: Try to convert my code to javascript and run it in a new, independent HTML page so you can just print the output to the console or append it as text to some `div` element. You may also want to look at http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/ to test your code.